# Why this function returned object whithin this expressjs route handler becomes undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services, express, httprequest

I'm creating an application  with expressjs that sends live data from mongodb to a javascript client, which requests the webservice periodically.
The application goal is to display them with highcharts library.

The problem is that i'm enable to pass the data to the client.

My questions are :

1. Why the reponse object is correct whithin the getLiveData() function and then becomes undefined when called by

   ```
   app.get("/liveDataRequest", function(req, res){ etc ...  ?
   ```
2. Why the requestData() function gets called only when the following two lines are commented :

   ```
   dataType: 'json',
   contentType: 'application/json',
   ```

These are the concerned parts of my code :

- Server side code : server.js

  ```
  function getLiveData(){
    var liveArray=[];
    var response;
    const changeStream = dbObject.collection('status').watch(pipeline);

  // start listening to changes
  changeStream.on("change", function(change) {
  console.log('in change stream');
  liveArray.push([change.fullDocument.ts , change.fullDocument.T]);

  response = {
      "liveArray" : liveArray
  };

  console.log("from getLiveData : " , reponse);
  return response;
  });      
  }

  app.get("/liveDataRequest", function(req, res){
  console.log('Debug 10');
  var liveResponse=getLiveData();
  console.log("liveResponse : " , liveResponse);
  res.status(200).send(liveResponse);
  console.log('Debug 20');
  });
  ```
- Client side code : client.js

  ```
  function requestData() {
  $.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost:3300/liveDataRequest',
  type: 'GET',
  //dataType: 'json',
  //contentType: 'application/json',
  success: function(point) {
      var series = myChart.series[0],
          shift = series.data.length > 20; // shift if the series is 
                                           // longer than 20

      // add the point
      myChart.series[0].addPoint(point.liveArray[0][1], true, shift);

      // call it again after one second
      setTimeout(requestData, 1000);    
  }
  });
  }
  ```

Here is the console output , which shows that before being sent to the client, the response object becomes undefined :

```
Debug 10
liveResponse :  undefined
Debug 20
in change stream
from getLiveData :  { liveArray: 
[ [ Fri Apr 13 2018 01:39:26 GMT-0400 (EDT), 24.5 ],
 [ Fri Apr 13 2018 01:39:28 GMT-0400 (EDT), 24.8 ] ] }
in change stream
from getLiveData :  { liveArray: 
[ [ Fri Apr 13 2018 01:39:25 GMT-0400 (EDT), 24.5 ],
 [ Fri Apr 13 2018 01:39:26 GMT-0400 (EDT), 24.5 ],
 [ Fri Apr 13 2018 01:39:28 GMT-0400 (EDT), 24.8 ] ] }
Debug 10
liveResponse :  undefined
Debug 20
Debug 10
liveResponse :  undefined
Debug 20
```

[console log capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXXWt.png)

PS: I'm new to using nodejs and javascript (and web technologies in general).

***Edit*** : Now i'm using a callback function whithin the getLiveData() function and i'm getting the following error :

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:335:11)
at ServerResponse.header (/home/osboxes/Desktop/node-highcharts-10/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:767:10)
at ServerResponse.send (/home/osboxes/Desktop/node-highcharts-10/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
at ServerResponse.json (/home/osboxes/Desktop/node-highcharts-10/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
at ServerResponse.send (/home/osboxes/Desktop/node-highcharts-10/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:158:21)
at /home/osboxes/Desktop/node-highcharts-10/server2.js:242:21
at null.<anonymous> (/home/osboxes/Desktop/node-highcharts-10/server2.js:200:9)
at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
at emit (events.js:169:7)
at processNewChange (/home/osboxes/Desktop/node-highcharts-10/node_modules/mongodb/lib/change_stream.js:348:49)
```

*new code :*

```
    app.get("/liveDataRequest", function(req, res){
      console.log('Debug 10');

      getLiveData(function(data){
      res.status(200).send(data);
      //res.json(data); //i get same error when i use this too
      console.log("in handler", data);
    });

    console.log('Debug 20');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem one:**

`getLiveData()` doesn't return anything here.
Your `return` is happening within a `changeStream.on(...)`

You could either use [`callbacks`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) or [`promises`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) here.

Callback example:

```
function getLiveData(handler){
    changeStream.on('change', function(change){
       //...
       handler(response);
    });
}

getLiveData(function(data){
    res.send(data);
});
```

Promise example:

```
function getLiveData(){
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        changeStream.on('change', function(change){
           //...
           resolve(response);
        }).on('error', reject);
    });
}

getLiveData()
    .then(function (data) {
        res.send(data)
    })
    .catch(console.error.bind(console));
```

**Problem two:**

It's probable the function does get called, but because the response that comes back isn't valid `JSON` (it'll be `undefined`), the success callback doesn't get fired (the error callback will).

You can verify this by looking in the `network` tab of your dev-tools.

Comment: in the second part of the callback example , is it : **getLiveData(function(data){
    res.send(data);
});** 
or
**handler(function(data){
    res.send(data);
});** ?

Comment: Yes @Joseph, i didn't understand the usage of callbacks well when i posted that comment.

Comment: @Hayfa Okay, has the answer helped?

Comment: i used callbacks and the data was passed to the response of the request, but now after the request to **"/liveDataRequest"** is called once, i get this error : _"Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:335:11)
"_

Comment: @Hayfa this happens when calling `res.send` or `res.status` etc. multiple times on a single `res`.
You are probably storing `res` somewhere or are re-using it by mistake. Could you post the code somewhere?

Comment: I edited the question to add the new code. Is it happening because the **getLiveData()** and thus the **handler()** callback are called more than once ? I would like to highlight that this webservice is called periodically by ajax at the client side because i need the get the new updates of the database.

Comment: @Hayfa Ahh, I see.
The .on('change', ...) handler gets called multiple times.
Depending on how that works, you might want to try .on('end', ...) or modify the change handler to accumulate changes